# Different TextureCoordinateFunction in two faces of a surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, textures

Let us say that we have the following example from the Texture[] help page, modified with FaceForm[] to get different textures for the inner and outer faces:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1.16^v Cos[v] (1 + Cos[u]), -1.16^v Sin[
    v] (1 + Cos[u]), -2 1.16^v (1 + Sin[u])}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 
  6}, PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Specularity[White, 30], 
   FaceForm[Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]], 
    Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Roof"}]]]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 2 #5} &), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

but we want to have diferent TextureCoordinateFunction for the inside and outside faces, how can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[u_, v_] := {1.16^v Cos[v] (1 + Cos[u]), 
   -1.16^v Sin[v] (1 + Cos[u]), -2 1.16^v (1 + Sin[u])}

t1 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}];
t2 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Roof"}];

plotstyle1 =  Directive[Specularity[White, 30], FaceForm[Texture[t1], None]];
plotstyle2 =  Directive[Specularity[White, 30], FaceForm[None, Texture[t2]]];

tcf1 = {#4, 2 #5} &;
tcf2 = {#5, #4} &;
```

One possible way: Make two copies of the surface `f` (first with the options `PlotStyle -> plotstyle1` and `TextureCoordinateFunction -> tcf1`, the second with `PlotStyle -> plotstyle2` and `TextureCoordinateFunction -> tcf2`) and combine with `Show`:

```
{p1, p2} = ParametricPlot3D[f[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -15, 6}, 
     PlotStyle -> #, TextureCoordinateFunction -> #2, 
     Lighting -> "Neutral", Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]& @@@
 {{plotstyle1, tcf1}, {plotstyle2, tcf2}};


Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

Comment: I don't know why Show[] does not work in 12.3.1. I have test  in Windows, Linux and Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: @cvgmt, I added version information. It looks like some things changed in version 12.+;  `PlotStyle ->FaceForm[ Texture[img], None]` works as expected but `PlotStyle ->FaceForm[ None, Texture[img]]` does not (Wolfam Cloud).

Comment: Another question is that the `Lighting -> "Neutral"` seems doesn't take effect in `Show[]`.